# Prevent starting processes automatically

Tags: services, ps, process-management, upstart

How can I prevent starting processes automatically.
(e.g. I used mysql database about a year ago). I killed
the `mysqld` processs and now I see it's running again.
And many other processes I don't know what are they good for.

I'd like to have more control over the processes that are running,
what I can turn off, what will start periodically etc.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

Comment: Please add your distribution and version to the question.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro done

Comment: If you mean daemons that start during boot, you can use `update-rc.d name disable` to disable it from starting (this works on Debian, please update your post with distro/version numbers)

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. At a very low level processes (apart from process number 1) start as a result of the fork or clone system calls. Something like mysqld will probably be started at boot time because of files in /etc/rc?.d, /lib/systemd/system or /etc/systemd/system depending on the `init` system you are running.

Comment: @Zwans Can I see all the processes that can start automatically?

Comment: @xralf yes that's possible, I check this by using the `ls /etc/rc*.d` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an override for the service.

Search for the service in /etc/init/. I have no mysql so I dont't know the exakt name.

I take pulseaudio for example.

```
ls -al /etc/init/ | grep pulse
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1890 Apr  4  2014 pulseaudio.conf
```

Then create the override-file for your Service

```
sudo touch /etc/init/pulseaudio.override
```

Then we will set the Service to manual.

```
echo "manual" | sudo tee -a /etc/init/pulseaudio.override
```

If you need the service you can start him manually with `sudo service pulseaudio start`

If you need your Service at boot again remove the createt file.

Could not better explain, my english ist very bad.